# Is it possible to display a landscape in app purchase sheet on iOS 11?

Tags: in-app-purchase, storekit, ios11

We're making a game that runs in landscape orientation. When running on iOS 11, we noticed that when requesting a payment the IAP prompt shows now as a portrait payment sheet (instead of a popup, like it used to on prior iOS versions).

Is it possible to display this new payment sheet in landscape orientation? I've searched Apple's documentation, but the only reference I could find to this new behavior is a passing mention in a WWDC 17 video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/303/ around 8:30). Also, when testing on the sandbox environment, the payment confirmation shows using the old popup.

Comment: Looks like it's a feature now :(

Comment: I hope not... It looks broken on landscape apps, especially since it takes up just half the screen.

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Comment: Commenting to state that it is still the case that the old popup is appearing in the sandbox environment, in iOS 11.2.2.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing new to add. We haven't looked further into this as it seems that's just the way it works now. My guess is this has to do with Face ID on the iPhone X only working in portrait mode. (For iPhone X they need to show the portrait popup as it would be awkward to ask you to turn your phone to pay, and they probably chose to make it consistent across all devices.)